# How do I calculate number of letters in a word in Tcl

Tags: list, split, tcl

I am getting the answer as 1 
I tried this :

```
set a "Amazon"
set b [split $a]
set c [llength $b]
puts "$c"
```

Comment: `split` splits on whitespace by default, so `b` will contain only 1 element (the entire word).

Comment: However, if you pass and empty string as second argument to `split`, your solution works, even if it's not an elegant solution. That is, replace the second line with `set b [split $a ""]`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use `string length` for that:

```
set a "Amazon"
set lengthOfA [string length $a]
puts "Length is: $lengthOfA"
```

Comment: Definitely use `string length` and not `string byte`, as the latter will return a different value if the word contains multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
set a "amazon"
set a [split "$a" ""]
puts [llength $a]
```

Comment: That's like going round the block to reach the other side of your driveway. Works, but ever so inefficient!